# Why did this materials bake result in mostly black except for one area?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, texture-baking

These are cycles materials, they have all been given an image texture node set to the same image, it has all been UV unwrapped and laid out so there are no overlapping parts, I tried flipping the normals, and recalculating the normals and flipping again, and again. After that first bake where part worked, the following bakes came out all black. I had dropped the sample number to 10 just to test, so I tried a bit higher, at 40, which is what the preview render setting is and that looks alright. Still all black.

[image: blender bake problem]

[image]

Comment: Wait - when i look at the scene in texture view, a previous bake shows up. That looks like it could be the problem. I'll delete that and try again.

Comment: Have you added a material just for the bake ? You don't need that. Only add a texture node where you have useful materials. Also all the UV parts are in one material which is nearly black. As you have several materials you may assign the wanted faces (so indirectly the corresponding UV map parts) to their material

Comment: @lemon No, the materials are the ones that are intended. I forgot to delete an emission shader i set up just to see the result. And another one wasn't hooked up to the output node for the same reason - i had been fiddling with it and didn't rejig it in the example file.

Comment: So all is ok now ?

Comment: What I see is (except one face) all the faces are assigned to DugoutLevels-painted2 which is black (no shader). The other face is assigned to DugouElevator-basaltMIPrough which is nearly black too. I am talking about this object : DugoutLevels

Comment: Ooooh - i had to retopologize, so i rebuilt that object, and i didn't reassign the materials to the faces. Criminy... :P Guess you solved it @lemon, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

First material was not connected to Material Output.